# Why is app size showing different in analyze apk and App info in android system?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, android-resources

I have made a simple application of a Minesweeper game. When i build and analyze the apk of the application , it shows apk size is 4.4 mb and download size is 3.7 mb. But, when i install the application in the emulator or a physical device, the app info of the application shows total app size as 11.43 mb.
Where is the rest of the space going?

[image]

Comment: Treat the .apk file as a ZIP, so it's more likely 4.4mb is the decompress size

Comment: APK is itself a compressed package, when you install on device it extract the components according to device architecture that's where the size is increased